# Free online image libraries of trachoma

Tags: infectious-diseases

I'm looking for an online source with images of the eye disease trachoma. I'm looking preferably for resources from a credible source that have images from each stage of the disease.

Answer (score 2):

According to wikipedia there are two different way to [distinguish stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trachoma#Diagnosis) of the disease. One is from McCallan and one from the World health organisation (WHO). For the second one, on WHO website, you can find [their grading card](http://www.who.int/neglected_diseases/resources/SAFE_documents/en/) with eyes images. You can download it with also a little description.

Hope it helps.